# Can I use .htpasswd to secure a nonexistent directory (a virtual mod_rewrite directory)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I use the front controller pattern and so all requests are routed through my index.php file.  I'd like to secure the 'Admin' controller (accessible at mysite/admin/) with .htpasswd.  Only problem is, 'admin' is not a directory but is just a mod_rewrite.  Can this be done?

Comment: Where does the rewrite point?

Comment: It *might* be possible by wrapping the `Allow from / Deny from` statements into a condition that checks `REQUEST_URI` for the admin directory

Comment: I think you can put the directives to protect that URL with basic auth in a `<Location>` section... or maybe you have to protect the rewritten URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not only one way, I'm pretty sure. You can create access control with mod_rewrite and `[F]` on any criteria you would have defined. See for example [Access control with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html#rewrite). That said you can perfectly do this.

```
<Location /admin>
   [here your rules]
</Location>
```

The [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require) directive has for [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) directory which means that you can use it the context of

```
<Directory>, <Location>, <Files>, and <Proxy>
```

:)